# How can I make icon loading work with late binding and tree shaking in Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am using a Flutter [Icon Package](https://github.com/flutter-studio/flutter-icons) 
which in the old version was loading Icons by a String parameter
like this:

```
Old Version works fine with late binding:

Icon(Ionicons.getIconData("ios-search"));
Icon(AntDesign.getIconData("stepforward"));
Icon(FontAwesome.getIconData("glass"));
```

All worked but because the icons are loaded by string the compiler has no knowledge of what Icons are used in runtime. That I think means that Tree shaking will not work. That also means that all Icon will be present in Code and make the apk unnecessary big.

Quote:
*Tree shaking. In computing, tree shaking is a dead code elimination technique that is applied when optimizing code written in ECMAScript dialects like Dart, JavaScript, or TypeScript into a single bundle that is loaded by a web browser.*

In the new version of that library, all Icons are statics and yes the compiler can use Tree-shaking but I use the String names to describe the icons in a plugin API. That just means that I can not use the library anymore. I implemented a caching code to load the Icons only once in the first case.

```
New version works fine with tree-shaking:

Icon(AntDesign.stepforward),
Icon(Ionicons.ios_search),
Icon(FontAwesome.glass),
```

The question is. Do I miss anything? How can I do both? Late binding and Tree-shaking. Maybe code generation? Better ideas?